# C# override ~ to take a function

Tags: c#, operators, overloading

I ideally I want to implement something like `var queryResult = ~( () => function(arg) );`

I wrote an automation framework and I am getting tired of writing long lines of code for it. It uses query to search through UIs and other data sources. So I figured, since this project is separate from source, I can get away with mucking around with operators. The below compiles fine, but I get an error:

**Cannot apply operator '~' to operand of type lambda expression**

```
public struct Query<T>
{
    public static Query<T> operator ~(Query<T> func)
    {
        return Poll.IdleFor(() => func, 10000);
    }
}
```

In another part of the code that is working I have a method signature like this:

`static T  IdleFor<T>(Func<T> arg, long waitTimeInMilliseconds)<T>(Func<T> arg, long milliseconds)`

And I call it via `MyStaticClass.IdleFor( () => myFunction(val), 10000)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `~` is unary, so you can't give it a parameter. [Overloadable Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: What does this `~` supposed to do? negate?

Comment: I was trying to mimic a jquery style $ so eventually I would change my test code to look more like $('#sdsd').DoSomething() i.e. ~(() => findElement('#sdsd')).DoSomething()

Comment: @crashmstr It's unary, so it must have *one* parameter.  That's what unary means...

Comment: @Servy ...they don't give examples like this on MSDN, and usually you would have the object itself be this one parameter (but the signature would have no parameters).

Comment: @crashmstr No, that's not correct.  Operator overloads are not equivalent to instance methods.  The first operand is not implicit.  This is why you see the "static" keyword in there.  You are effectively writing a static method, and the operand is *explicitly* provided for *all* operators.

Comment: @Servy doh. too much C++ on the brain.

Comment: @LLL: I question the utility of this.  In contrast to javascript, in C# you usually just access your variables by name (which gives you great intellisense).  There are of course a few exceptions (e.g., often needing `FindControl` when working with Asp.Net templates).

Comment: The variables may not exist immediately and it is variable when they will be loaded. It is a general command I wrote for test automation. It works great for dynamic web pages and data retrieval. It is not a solve-all solution by any means though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can get away with mucking around with operators.

That is a really, really bad attitude in C#. "Mucking around with operators" to make semantics other than math semantics is a bad practice in C# and I strongly discourage you from attempting to do so.

I note that you did not ask an answerable question. "What am I missing?" is not a specific enough question to answer. So let's propose some answerable questions:

> Is it possible to overload a unary operator in C# such that the operand of that operator can be a lambda expression?

No.

> How are overloaded unary operators resolved in C#?

First the type of the operand is determined. From this type, a list of overloaded operators is created. Overload resolution then proceeds more or less as it does with method overload resolution, treating the operand as an argument and the operators as methods.

> So why does this not work with lambdas?

I said *first the type of the operand is determined*. Lambdas do not have a type. Therefore there is no list of overloaded operators upon which to perform overload resolution in the first place.

Comment: Interesting, so it is a semantics limitation of the language. Thanks for adding an explanation of the language details.